# Explain Pandas reset _index() level arguments?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can someone please explain level and col_level argument of the reset_index() in the pandas. Read the documentation and tried myself as well but didn't understand.

New in the Pandas

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) documentation has a pretty good example. Those parameters determine the source and destination levels of moving an index to column.

Assuming this dataframe:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('bird', 'falcon'),
                                   ('bird', 'parrot'),
                                   ('mammal', 'lion'),
                                   ('mammal', 'monkey')],
                                  names=['class', 'name'])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('speed', 'max'),
                                     ('species', 'type')])
df = pd.DataFrame([(389.0, 'fly'),
                   (24.0, 'fly'),
                   (80.5, 'run'),
                   (np.nan, 'jump')],
                  index=index,
                  columns=columns)

               speed species   # <─ column level 0
                 max    type   # <─ column level 1
class  name
bird   falcon  389.0     fly
       parrot   24.0     fly
mammal lion     80.5     run
       monkey    NaN    jump
# ^     ^
# │     └─── index level 1/"name"
# └───────── index level 0/"class"
```

Then we can move the index level "class" as column and choose to insert the column name in the second level (1):

```
df.reset_index(level='class', col_level=1)

                speed species
         class    max    type  # <─ "class" was moved to the second level (1)
name
falcon    bird  389.0     fly
parrot    bird   24.0     fly
lion    mammal   80.5     run
monkey  mammal    NaN    jump
```

Let's try another example, now moving the "name" level (here indexed by its position: `1`), to the top level of the columns:

```
df.reset_index(level=1, col_level=0)

          name  speed species  # <─ "name" was moved to the first level (0)
                  max    type
class                        
bird    falcon  389.0     fly
bird    parrot   24.0     fly
mammal    lion   80.5     run
mammal  monkey    NaN    jump
```

Comment: Now I got it. Maybe the documentation is missing those comment which you have added explicitly. Thanks for your effort.